# Couchbase + PHP SDK slow establishing connection to

Tags: php, database, couchbase

I'm having issue using the SDK for PHP.

If I try to estabilish a connection it takes ages...

Here some code:

```
$old = microtime (true);
$db = new Couchbase(...);
echo microtime (true)-$old."
";
$old = microtime (true);
$db->get(...);
echo microtime (true)-$old;
```

The output is this:
2.2835459709167 (couchbase establishing)
0.0011978149414062 (get command)

Why does the connection to couchbase take so long time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial connection does take a while, but there is a flag for using persistent connections with the Couchbase() object.  It's the last parameter.  Generally, it's a good idea to set it to true.

The project is considering setting it to true by default in a future release.

Comment: That's it thx! Funny that it always worked fast (without that flag) but somehow it started working slow. Works fine now!

Answer (score 0):

Check which value you're using for the server host, if you use, for example:

```
$cb = new Couchbase("couchbase_hostname:8091", "user", "pass", "default" , true);
```

the issue may be the DNS resolution for "couchbase_hostname", try passing the host IP, you didn't paste the whole script code so I can't tell which value you're passing.